# Minecraft 'testfor' dummy objective not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have managed to figure out most of this scoreboard system out myself but this last part has me beaten.

i have a dummy Objective called "deaths" and would like to test when this score hits 10 for team_blue and team_red.

I currently have;

> /testfor @a[score_deaths_min=1,team=team_red]

but this is not working. I am also using;

> /testfor @a[score_Score_min=10,team=team_red]

This is to test when a player dies and adds that to the "deaths" score, and that works perfectly fine.
Is there an issue of using dummy objectives in the testfor command. Console output only says "That players cannot be found"

---

I am including a world download for testing purposes. Please note the objective names have Changed. Red and Blue carpet mark Teams and Signs give information. This is for vanilla 1.7.2: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189120588/Minecraft/testfor%20world.zip

Comment: Is the dummy objective called "Deaths?" Then it should be /testfor @a[score_Deaths_min=1,team=team_red]

Comment: The fact that it's a dummy objective has nothing to do with it, IF you know it DOES IN FACT work perfectly fine. How are you sure it works fine?

Comment: i think something got mixed up when people edited it or when i was typing it. "deaths" is the dummy objective that is not working, "Score" is the deathCount objective that works fine.

Comment: Oh, I got the answer then!

Comment: I got confused when editing, I may have switched the two out of my own mistake.

Comment: Still looking for answers for this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to increment by 1 anytime a player dies, the objective must be type deathCount.
Something like this would work:

`/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount Deaths`

If you're making dummy objectives, you're using a similar command except with "dummy" in place of "deathCount."
A dummy objective can only be changed with the following commands:

`/scoreboard players add (player) (objective) (value)`

`/scoreboard players remove (player) (objective) (value)`, and

`/scoreboard players set (player) (objective) (value)`

Comment: i have all that, The code
    /testfor @a[score_deaths_min=1,team=team_blue]
is what is not working. "deaths" is a dummy objective as "Score" is the death counter objective.

Comment: @AceScottie Aww. I thought I had finally got it. Is the team called "team_blue?" Or just blue? If the former, then... are you using a comparator for the output? And if yes, then... are you signalling the command block continuously on a fast timer? And if yes, then... idk.

Comment: That is, idk IF of this dummy objective, "deaths," you are ABSOLUTELY sure increments correctly. Check this with /scoreboard players list @p

Comment: team is team_blue, yes its a comparator and yes fast timer. you can see it all in the world download i added. and everything else is working since i used "deaths" multiple times to create the scoreboard. (i changed it to "Score" in the world)